# php mail with sender

Tags: php, email, post

In this mailform everything things work except there is no sender and my mail is going straight to the trash! is it because theres no sender on this mailform? And I want to se the information from the sender so a wonder where do I fill in the code from sender?

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail = "xxxxx@live.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = check_input($_POST['inputName'], "Your Name");
$email = check_input($_POST['inputEmail'], "Your E-mail Address");
$subject = check_input($_POST['inputSubject'], "Message Subject");
$message = check_input($_POST['inputMessage'], "Your Message");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("Invalid e-mail address");
}
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */


$message = "

Someone has sent you a message from xxxxxxx.com:

Name: $name
Email: $email
Subject: $subject

Message:
$message

";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: http://www.xxxxxxx.com/confirmation.html');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>

  <body>

    <p>Please correct the following error:</p>
    <strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
    <p>Hit the back button and try again</p>

  </body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: From the manual (mail): When sending mail, the mail must contain a From header. This can be set with the additional_headers parameter, or a default can be set in php.ini.

Comment: Having said that, I just checked my LAMP setup, and I have no 'sendmail_from' value defined in my config.  My mailer (exim4), is adding a From field for the user that runs the script if I don't add the header.  Do you have no From header at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add in the sender's email address using the "additional headers" argument to mail:

```
mail($myemail, $subject, $message, "From: sender@example.com");
```

**Edit**: in your case, I think you need to pass in the $email variable defined earlier in your code.  That will show the email as coming from the email address that was entered in the form.

```
mail($myemail, $subject, $message, "From: " . $email);
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Thanks Will for your time! But when I get a mail a want to see in the header who´s it comes from. In this example, it is saying sender@example.com or which email i fill in.

Comment: Thanks  a lot Will!